# Where does PERL LWP::Simple getstore save the image?

Tags: perl, http

I am trying to use perl getstore to get a list of image from URL after reading a text file containing the file names, I created the code and able to run it successfully but I do not know where is the file saved, i checked the disk size it and shows that every time i run the code the hard disk free space decrease, so i assume there are file saved but I can't find it. So where does perl getstore save file and what is the correct way to save image from a link ?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = "https://labs.jamesooi.com/images/";
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36");

my $file = 'image-list.txt';
open (DATA, $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while(<DATA>){
  my $link = "$url" . "$_";
  my $filename = "$_";
  print $link;
  print $filename;

  my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $link);
  my $res = $ua->request($req);
  if($res->is_success){
    my $rc = getstore($link, $filename);
    if(is_success($rc)){
      print "Success\n";
    }else{
      print "Error\n";
    }
  } else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: It gets stored in the `$filename` you give as second argument. If this is a relative name it is treated relative to the current working directory. But, why do you first do a GET and then to another GET (implicit inside `getstore`) instead just saving the response you've already got?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That should be an (the) answer, maybe expanded with a suggestion to prepend the destination directory to `$filename`.  The question is marginal at best (answer really is "read the docs") but it might help someone in the future.

Comment: the    $filename is koala1.jpg, i searched the working directory but i found nothing other than the perl file. The GET is just for me to confirm the code can get a connection to the url, that's what i think I'm doing, I'm very new to perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to
[the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Simple#getstore),
`getstore(url, file)` takes the URL as the first argument and the second argument is the file name where the result is stored. If the file name is a relative path (it doesn't begin with a slash `/`) it will be relative to the current working directory.

But you read the name from a file and then treat the full line, including the newline character, as the file name. That's probably not what you want, so you should use `chomp` to remove the newline.

Apart from that:

- You are doing first a `GET` request using `LWP::UserAgent` to retrieve the file but ignore the response and instead call `getstore` to retrieve and store the same resource if the first `GET` was successful. It would be simpler to either just save the result from the first `GET` or just skip it and use only `getstore`.
- You are using `DATA` as a file handle. While this is not wrong, `DATA` is already an implicit file handle which points to the program file after the `__DATA__` marker, so I recommend to use a different file handle.

When using a simplified version of the code the file gets successfully stored:

```
use strict;
use warnings;    

use LWP::Simple;

my $url  = "https://labs.jamesooi.com/images/";
my $file = 'image-list.txt';

open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {

    chomp;  # remove the newline from the end of the line

    my $link     = $url . $_;
    my $filename = $_;

    my $rc = getstore($link, $filename);

    if (is_success($rc)) {
        print "Success\n";
    }
    else {
        print "Error\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: the $filename is koala1.jpg, i searched the working directory but i found nothing other than the perl file.

Comment: @UndeadLeftClick: see edited response - the problem is probably that you've left the newline at the end of the name.